# References and URL rules in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a problem with my simple app in Flask. I want to write a registration page, that connect with datebase by SQLAlchemy. I've got **app.py** file that look like this:

```
import flask
import settings
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Views
from main import Main
from login import Login
from remote import Remote
from register import Register
#from models import User
#from models import Task

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Routes
app.add_url_rule('/',
                 view_func=Main.as_view('main'),
                 methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule('/<page>/',
                 view_func=Main.as_view('page'),
                 methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule('/login/',
                 view_func=Login.as_view('login'),
                 methods=["GET", "POST"])
app.add_url_rule('/remote/',
                 view_func=Remote.as_view('remote'),
                 methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.add_url_rule('/register/',
                 view_func=Register.as_view('register'),
                 methods=['GET', 'POST'])

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return flask.render_template('404.html'), 404

app.debug = True
app.run()
```

So, as you can see I have URL rules in this file and now I want to use **db** variable in **Register** view, so I need import it there, my code for this file looks like this:

```
import flask, flask.views
from app import db

class Register(flask.views.MethodView):
    def get(self):
        return flask.render_template('register.html')

    def post(self):
        new_user = User(username = request.form['username'], 
                        password = request.form['passwd']
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
```

In that case I get error, cause I have "tied" references, in **app** file is:

```
from register import Register
```

but in **Register** file is

```
from app import db
```

So it, obviously can't work, my solutions is to add URL rule in **Register** file. But I don't know how. Could you anyone help me?

Sorry for my confusing title, but I just getting started with Flask and I dnon't know how to name it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `db` assignment to *before* the imports that expect `db` to exist:

```
import flask
import settings
import os
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Views
# These can now use
#     from app import db
# because that line has executed above
from main import Main
from login import Login
from remote import Remote
from register import Register
#from models import User
#from models import Task
```

Now when you import the `register` module and the `from app import db` line runs, the `db` variable actually exists in the `app` module.

Note that you cannot now use `app.py` as the *main script*; if you use `python app.py` then it'll be imported as the `__main__` module instead of `app` module, and using `from app import db` will create a *new* module, separate from the main script.

Either use a separate serving script, like `serve.py` and move your `app.run()` call into that file:

```
from app import app
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

or use `from __main__ import db`.

You also are missing a closing `)` in your `register` module:

```
new_user = User(username = request.form['username'], 
                password = request.form['passwd']
#              ^                                 ^
```

Comment: @user3448282: you are missing the closing parenthesis on the *previous* line. `new_user = User(username = request.form['username'], password = request.form['passwd']` is not a complete statement.

Comment: @user3448282: when posting a question, always include the full error message; I made a specific assumption here about the error you'd encounter (which you'd encounter anyway, regardless of the syntax error), but you could have helped matters greatly had you included that error in your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry for getting you confused, I should post my error log. Unfortunately I still get [errors](http://pastebin.com/uzmk0f5c)

Comment: @user3448282: you are runnig `app.py` as the main script?